# How to list cookies with changes in AspNet Core

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

In my application I have filter that sets cookie:

`HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("myCookie", "value")`

When I print cookie value in my view:

`HttpContext.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];`

it is not there. If I refresh page cookie is set. This happens because using `Response.Cookies.Append` does not update `Request.Cookies` collection. Is there way to view current cookies with changes made during request?

In my web application I have `IAsyncActionFilter`, that updates cookie, however corrected value is visible only after page is refreshed, and I would like to finish current request with new value. I know that it will be set by browser when response finishes, but I already know that I have new value for that cookie, and I would like to propagate this value to views reading cookies.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is how cookies work. They are sourced from the client. In other words, the cookie is set by the client after it receives the response from the server with the `Set-Cookie` header. It's then only after the client makes another request, sending the cookie back, that it exists server-side. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve ultimately here, but you need to force a new request after setting a cookie, to access that cookie, even if that's simply returning a redirect to the same page.

Comment: Added problem description to question. Basically cookie caches text, and if that text is updated in backend I would like both to set new cookie and use new value.

Comment: A cookie is not an appropriate place for caching. Regardless, the point remains the same: you have to have a separate request from the client first.

Comment: Let's say cookies stores user preferred language, and when user click change language banner page reloads in old language.

Comment: Use the PRG (Post Redirect Get) pattern. Selecting a language should cause a POST request. The action handling that should set the cookie and return a redirect. If the user needs to go back to the same page, then redirect to the same page, but you need to redirect. This will cause the user's browser to issue a new GET request for that page, where the cookie will be passed. Do not simply return the view directly. That's where your problem is.

Comment: Sadly I cannot use PRG. In my situation someone is using french (fr) language, and he visits `website.com/en/stuff`. I know that someone wants to see website in English, so I update cookie. However I don't always have language parameter in url, so it is better for frontend dudes to read data from cookie (ofc it's simplification). If someone clicks on 'view in english'  button I am using PRG pattern.

Comment: I know that I could make proper abstraction for language stuff, but it's asap driver development :). Anyway the point is there should be no reason to delay Request.Cookies update to next request, framework should update it automagically, because it knows, that value stored in cookie changed.

Comment: For something like the URL, you can use a resource filter to set the cookie and then redirect back to the same URL again (check if cookie exists first to prevent infinite redirect).

Comment: That's not an option :( I don't have problem with application design, or http protocol, but with Asp.Net Core framework, which does not track new cookie values.